# What is the correct syntax for filtering by tag in describe-vpcs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-cli

I am trying to understand a aws ec2 cli call. I am looking to describe all VPC then filer on a custom tag (vpcname=myvpc, however after trying multiple combinations I keep getting conflicting errors about the format and use of --filters. using as a reference [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-vpcs.html][1]

> aws --profile myProfile --region eu-west-1 ec2 describe-vpcs --filters
>   vpcname,myvpc

however this returns

```
Error parsing parameter '--filters': should be: Key value pairs, where values are separated by commas, and multiple pairs are separated by spaces.
--filters Name=string1,Values=string1,string2 Name=string1,Values=string1,string2
```

so trying

> aws --profile myProfile --region eu-west-1 ec2 describe-vpcs --filters
>   Name=vpcname,Values=myvpc

and it returns

```
A client error (InvalidParameterValue) occurred when calling the DescribeVpcs operation: The filter 'vpcname' is invalid
```

so trying a few other combinations

```
aws --profile myProfile --region eu-west-1 ec2 describe-vpcs --filters tag :Name=vpcname,Values=myvpc

Error parsing parameter '--filters': should be: Key value pairs, where values are separated by commas, and multiple pairs are separated by spaces.
--filters Name=string1,Values=string1,string2 Name=string1,Values=string1,string2
```

Any advice on how I format this request?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You got pretty close to solving it -- the only problem is that you are not specifying a [valid filter for describe-vpcs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-vpcs.html).  Here's the filter that would be relevant to your use case:

```
tag:key=*value* - The key/value combination of a tag assigned to the resource.
```

So when it is asking for `Name=string1,Values=string1...`, it expects:

- Name=tag:TagName
- Values=TagValue

Try this instead, works for me locally with a different custom tag:

```
aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filters Name=tag:vpcname,Values=myvpc
```

Comment: could you take a look at a follow on question, I have applied your answer to a new CLI but do not get expected result     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119010/correct-aws-cli-syntax-to-find-find-a-vpc-security-group-in-a-non-default-vpc thanks Art

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a simple and effective way:

aws --profile sep-test --region eu-west-1 ec2 describe-vpcs --filters Name=tag:name,Values=myvpc

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do the same thing using the Ansible AWS *_facts calls you have the same kind of issue. In Ansible the correct syntax is:

`ec2_vpc_net_facts:
    filters:
        "tag:vpcname": "myvpc"`

I only mention this here because this SO question came up in most of my google searches when trying to get the Ansible right and I had been using the AWS cli example above in Ansible because I couldn't get the filter right.

Answer (score -1):

Define tag in TAG variable and value in VALUE variable:

```
TAG=vpcname
VALUE=myvpc
aws ec2 describe-vpcs |\
jq -r ".Vpcs[] | select (.Tags[] | select(.Key==\"$TAG\") |\
select(.Value==\"$VALUE\"))"
```