# correct aws cli syntax to find a VPC security group in a non default VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-cli

This is a follow on question from [What is the correct syntax for filtering by tag in describe-vpcs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057932/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-filtering-by-tag-in-describe-vpcs).

Using the answer provided and referencing http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html

```
--filters (list)
One or more filters.
......
vpc-id - The ID of the VPC specified when the security group was created.
```

I have constructed the cli request

```
aws --profile myProfile --region eu-west-1 ec2 describe-security-groups --group-name MyVpcSecGroup --filters Name=tag:vpc-id,Values=vpc-9xxxxxxx
```

however I get an error

> The security group 'MyVpcSecGroup' does not exist in default VPC
>   'vpc-bxxxxxx'

So how do I format the syntax to search for a security group in a non default VPC using a list of --filters such as vpc-id?

thx Art

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation says:

```
   --group-names (list)
      [EC2-Classic, default VPC] One or more security group names.
```

So, it would seem that `--group-names` cannot be used on a non-default VPC.

However, there are alternative methods:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-xxxxxxxx
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=group-name,Values=MyVpcSecGroup
```

To filter based on a specific **VPC and Name**:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-11223344 Name=group-name,Values=MyVpcSecGroup
```

To filter based on a specific **VPC and any Tag**:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-11223344 Name=tag-value,Values=Production
```

To filter based on a specific **VPC and a specific Tag**:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-11223344 Name=tag:Environment,Values=Production
```

Note: Tag names and values are **case-sensitive**.

Comment: Thanks @John, My question was ambiguous so I have added some info to the last sentence. I wish to get the MyVpcSecGroup info by filtering based on a tag, such as vpc-id. That should return ifo for the specific group-ids for a specific VPC.  Thx Art

Comment: Updated to include examples of filtering by Tag.

Comment: perfect @John, adding the group-name as a filter was what I was missing, Art

Answer (score 2):

Here's how we do it when looking for a specific group:

```
aws --profile myProfile ec2 describe-security-groups --region=AWS_REGION --filters "Name=vpc-id,Values=VPC_ID" --filters "Name=group-name,Values=NAMEOFSECGROUP"
```

Comment: thanks for your input, giving a +1 for quotes as in some cases the names were failing without them, Art